# What is the difference between verifying the hash value (MAC) and security provided by authenticated encryption?

Tags: mac, authenticated-encryption

I read this post [Difference between MAC and Authenticated Encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33684/difference-between-mac-and-authenticated-encryption) but I'm still confusing the difference.

Seems like MAC can guarantee both integrity and authenticity (tbh I dont know the difference of integrity and authenticity).

What is the difference of MAC and AE?
Is AE using MAC?

Answer (score 1):

Authenticated encryption also keeps the message secret.

Often, though not necessarily, authenticated encryption is built out of a composition of a cipher and a MAC—which, if you have to do yourself out of parts like AES-CTR and HMAC-SHA256, you should do as encrypt-then-MAC.

<sub>P.S.  There is no substantive difference between authenticity and integrity.  They both answer the question: Was this message sent by the party I expected to send it?</sub>